Window functions in Trino: ordering changes length of array
TL;DR: If I order a window-function partition, then the length of the resulting array changes.
Here's a minimal example. We first generate some toy data:
select *
from (
  values
    (date('1900-01-01'),1,'a')
   ,(date('1900-01-02'),2,'a')
   ,(date('1900-01-03'),3,'a')
     ) a(date,id,customer)

The resulting data looks like this:

Now the window functions:
with data as (

select *
from (
  values
    (date('1900-01-01'),1,'a')
   ,(date('1900-01-02'),2,'a')
   ,(date('1900-01-03'),3,'a')
     ) a(date,id,customer)

select
  date
 ,id
 ,customer
 ,array_agg(id) over (partition by customer) as ids
 ,array_agg(id) over (partition by customer order by date) as ids_ordered
from
  data


Why does order by date affect the length of the arrays? Is this a bug or expected behaviour?
My deployment: (a slightly modified version of) version 0.8.0 of the Trino chart.

Sounds like a bug to me, but maybe not for ORDER BY case but the one without it. By default windows functions use RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW frame which is true for both aggregates and can be confirmed with explain:

Since ordering is undefined for the ids it should result in "random" arrays and maybe it is treated as a special case by Trino (but could not find this anywhere).
If your goal is to have the result as for orderless case then change the frame to RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING:
select
  date
 ,id
 ,customer
 ,array_agg(id) over (partition by customer ) as ids
 ,array_agg(id) over (partition by customer order by date RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)   as ids_ordered
from
  data
order by date;

Output:



date
id
customer
ids
ids_ordered




1900-01-01
1
a
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]


1900-01-02
2
a
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]


1900-01-03
3
a
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]



